# How to optimize query with multiple LIKE predicates

Tags: sql, optimization, firebird

I want to extract all the personnes that have a 'valeur_lisible', or a 'lnk_attributs_objets.valeur' or a 'attribut.nom' equals to '%gingivite%'.

My request looks like that :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_PERSONNE, PER_NOM, PER_PRENOM 

FROM personne
    LEFT JOIN instance_fiche_personnalisee ON (personne.id_personne=instance_fiche_personnalisee.id_patient)
    LEFT JOIN objet ON (objet.id_patient = personne.id_personne)
    LEFT JOIN datas_instance_fiche_perso ON (instance_fiche_personnalisee.id_instance = datas_instance_fiche_perso.id_instance)
    LEFT JOIN lnk_attributs_objets ON (objet.pk_objet = lnk_attributs_objets.id_objet)
    LEFT JOIN attributs ON (lnk_attributs_objets.id_attribut = attributs.pk_attribut)

WHERE (LOWER(datas_instance_fiche_perso.valeur_lisible) like '%gingivite%')
    OR (LOWER(lnk_attributs_objets.valeur) like '%gingivite%') 
    OR (LOWER(attributs.nom) like '%gingivite%')
```

It takes already arround 4s on my small database (926 personnes).
Is there a way to optimize my request?
I am a beginner in SQL.

Remark : I used LEFT JOIN because a personne can have a valeur_lisible but no objets (attributs are linked to objets) and reverse.

**EDIT :** This is a scheme of the relationship between the tables :
[image]

I put in blue the values that I want to check as gingivite.

Comment: (1) Provide a database tag.  (2) Show the relationships between the tables and your current indexes.  (3) Show the execution plan for the query.

Comment: I can't wrap my head around why you would need so many joins on one table. Provide the table structure so it's clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Instead of joining all the tables resulting in duplicate rows from `personne` and then removing those duplicates using `distinct` it might be more efficient to only select from `personne` and use an `EXISTS` condition to get only those rows you are interested in.

Comment: I edited my post with an image of the tables structure. For the execution plan, I don't  know how to get it ... I work with Database Workbench 4

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : thanks for the tip ! I will look into this EXISTS condition

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using.

Comment: It is a FireBird database. I add it as a TAG right now

Comment: You should try to avoid the need for having to search using a containing like (`like '%...%'`) because Firebird cannot use an index for such a search. It also suggest that those fields are denormalized (containing lists of things/multiple values), and possibly a more normalized design would allow you to search quicker.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel since he uses `LOWER` in comparison - it would always go without index, unless there would be an index on expression. Frankly, it seems there is a need to yet another "dictionary" table X, that would contain "gingivite" and some other items as separate rows, and then all three tables of `datas_instance_fiche_perso` and `lnk_attributs_objets` and `attributs` would have `Foreign Key` links to X

Comment: There also was a project to attach some Java full-text-search library to Firebird, but it seems that niche solution did not get much interest form other developers.

Comment: @Arioch'The Unless you use a case insensitive collation, which would remove the need for lower.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel interesting, but then I still think it would be up to developer to remove `lower` call, I do not thing FB optimizer would be smart enough to remove that call without human interaction

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to significantly reduce the time for this request :
- Use UNION of INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN
- Put the WHERE condition in the INNER JOIN 'ON'

Here is my final request :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID_PERSONNE, PER_NOM, PER_PRENOM FROM personne 
          INNER JOIN instance_fiche_personnalisee ON (personne.id_personne=instance_fiche_personnalisee.id_patient) 
          INNER JOIN datas_instance_fiche_perso ON (instance_fiche_personnalisee.id_instance = datas_instance_fiche_perso.id_instance) 
               AND  LOWER(datas_instance_fiche_perso.valeur_lisible) like '%gingivite%' 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ID_PERSONNE, PER_NOM, PER_PRENOM FROM personne
       INNER JOIN objet ON (objet.id_patient = personne.id_personne)
       INNER JOIN lnk_attributs_objets ON (objet.pk_objet = lnk_attributs_objets.id_objet) AND (LOWER(lnk_attributs_objets.valeur) like '%gingivite%')            

UNION
SELECT DISTINCT ID_PERSONNE, PER_NOM, PER_PRENOM FROM personne
       INNER JOIN objet ON (objet.id_patient = personne.id_personne)
       INNER JOIN lnk_attributs_objets ON (objet.pk_objet = lnk_attributs_objets.id_objet)
       INNER JOIN attributs ON (lnk_attributs_objets.id_attribut = attributs.pk_attribut) AND (LOWER(attributs.nom) like '%gingivite%')
```

**It takes only 0.07s (instead of 4s before)**